# Create a dropdown menu within web page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, dropdown

Id like to understand how this form works, visit: http://www.sujood.co/

There should be a drop down, when you select an option, the screen changes to meet the dropdown. I am a wordpress.org user, is this possible? Is it html? a php form?

Also this guys, seems to reload the page, can you have it interactive, so its on one page?

Comment: You could do this using php and Javascript or just plain js, personally I would create a mysql table with responses and feelings and have an ajax call to query the database and display results inside an empty div.

Answer (score 2):

It's HTML and java script for sure. Likely some PHP in the back end to fetch info from a database. Just view the source..  Notice the `onchange="this.form.submit()"`
in the opening select tag. That makes it submit the form whenever you pick a new value.

```
<form action="/prayers" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get">
. . . . 
<select name="tags" id="tags" onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

Comment: Thanks. Ill see if i can find a wordpress plugin, Otherwise, doing it manually seems an effort. Im sure theres a short code.